# How to read Message from in-memory message-store through message-processo wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

i have stored messages in in-memory message-store(wso2 esb). 
How to read  Message from in-memory message-store.

Comment: To improve your chances of getting an answer, ask a good question. Please check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MessageProcessor for solve your task.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Adding+a+Message+Processor

So you can send it to "sequence" by "Sample Processor" or to endpoint by "Scheduled Processor"

I write below configuration for wso2esb/wso2ei. Then you can call url http://127.0.0.1:8280/test/store in browser.
It's will be work as:

---

api test -> store messsage in MemoryStore

Processor TestProcessor -> send message to sequence TestSequence every 200ms

TestSequence -> transform message and loopback response to outSequence of api

---

```
<messageStore name="TestStore"/>
<api context="/test" name="test">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/store">
        <inSequence>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <a xmlns="">1</a>
                </format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <store messageStore="TestStore"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
<messageProcessor  class="org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.sampler.SamplingProcessor"
    messageStore="TestStore" name="TestProcessor">
    <parameter name="sequence">TestSequence</parameter>
    <parameter name="interval">200</parameter>
    <parameter name="is.active">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="concurrency">1</parameter>
</messageProcessor>
<sequence name="TestSequence">
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <b xmlns="">$1</b>
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml"
                expression="//*[local-name()='a']/text()" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
    <loopback/>
</sequence>
```

Comment: can you share a sample code to read a message from in-memory store @Иван Емельянов

Comment: thanks for info. i called api, got response but message is not stored in messagestore  @Иван Емельянов

Comment: because it already was processed by message processor. If you change  interval to 20000 - you will get response in in 20 sec, and in this time you can have time to see message in messagestore. After 20 sec - it will disapear